# using COND on optional arguments in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, optional-parameters

I'm having some problem writing a LISP function. The function is defined as

```
(defun foo (arg1 &optional cont))
   (cond ((null arg1) nil)
         ((= 0 cont) arg1)
         ((do_something))
         ((recursive call))))
```

When i call the function with `cont` everything works fine, but when I call it just with arg1 the error returned is:

```
Error: in ZEROP of (NIL) arguments should be of type NUMBER
```

I guess something is wrong in the condition `((= 0 cont) arg1)`, can you help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to know if an optional argument is provided, you can do that: `(defun foo (arg1 &optional (cont nil contp))` ... for instance

Comment: Btw., the error message seems to indicate that the call to `=` has been replaced by a call to `zerop` by the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

The [`=`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ) function, along with some other ones, expect exclusively numbers.

You need to use [`EQL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#EQ) or a more general equality comparison (equal, equalp) when you expect NIL to be a valid input; here, NIL is expected because it is the default value of the optional argument.

You could also provide a numerical default value to `cont`:

```
 ... &optional (cont 0) ...
```

... which might be the correct approach if `cont` has no reason to be anything else than a number.

Comment: Alternative: the `cond`ition could be `(and (numberp cont) (= 0 cont))` if `cont` might have a reason not to be a number.